# How to use multiple LiveData into ViewModel in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

In my application I have **5 APIs** and response of this APIs are same. 
This APIs is for get product of categories. 
I create general fun for call API in **viewmodel** such as below

```
    private fun callProductData(category:String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        _productData.value = NetworkRequest.Loading()
        val response = repository.getProductList(category)
        _producta.value = NetworkResponse(response).generalNetworkResponse()
    }
```

Into **fragment** with below codes I called the API :

```
viewModel.callProductData("mobile")
viewModel.callProductData("tv")
viewModel.callProductData("shirts")
```

But I don't know how can I set multiple LiveData for get data from above fun . 
My full codes in viewmodel :

```
    private val _productData = MutableLiveData<NetworkRequest<ResponseProductsList>>()
    val productData: LiveData<NetworkRequest<ResponseProductsList>> = _productData

    private fun callProductData(category:String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        _productData.value = NetworkRequest.Loading()
        val response = repository.getProductList(category)
        _producta.value = NetworkResponse(response).generalNetworkResponse()
    }
```

In above code I can just set one LiveData and with one LiveData just get one category data!

How can I set dynamically **LiveData** for get products of category?

I think with below codes I can use multiple LiveData:

```
LiveData<NetworkRequest<Map<String, ResponseProductsList>>> 
_producta.value!![category] = /*response*/
```

**Fragment codes:**

```
private fun loadProductData() {
        binding.apply {
            viewModel.productData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { response ->
                when (response) {
                    is NetworkRequest.Loading -> {
                        productList.showShimmer()
                    }

                    is NetworkRequest.Success -> {
                        productList.hideShimmer()
                        response.data?.let { data ->
                            if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
                                initProductRecycler(data)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    is NetworkRequest.Error -> {
                        productList.hideShimmer()
                        root.showSnackBar(response.message!!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I don't know how can I use this into my above viewModel and fragment?

Comment: Someone else is asking about almost the same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76164686/how-to-call-api-with-coroutines-in-android/76165197#76165197). Maybe you are classmates with the same assignment. Anyway, you do need a separate LiveData for each request type. It doesn't make sense for all of them to share the same state. LiveData represents the state or status of one thing.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear for me, how you are storing the results in one live data and what its structere is.

If you have some List in your `productData`, then you could load all the data with one function and merge the results. Then put it into one LiveData

Also I would set `Loading` state outside courutine.

```
data class Product(
    ...
)

sealed class LoadingStatus {

    object Loading : LoadingStatus()

    data class Error(val err: Throwable) : LoadingStatus()

    data class Loaded(val data: HashMap<String, List<Product>>) : LoadingStatus ()

}

class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val productData: MutableLiveData<HashMap<String, List<Product>>> = mutableLiveData()

    private fun callProductData(categories: List<String>) {
        productData.value = LoadingStatus.Loading
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val hashMap = categories
                .asFlow()
                .flatMapMerge {
                    flow {
                        val response = repository.getProductList(category)
                        emit(category to response)
                    }
                }
                .catch { err -> productData.postValue(LoadingStatus.Error(err)) }
                .toHashMap()
            
            productData.postValue(LoadingStatus.Loaded(hashMap ))
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
    viewModel.callProductData(listOf("mobile", "tv", "apple"))
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. I have 5 api with same result but different categories names. such as : mobile - tv - shirts - foods and ... . I want know what is the best way for call this 5 apis ! I think  when write deferent live data fun such as above viewmodel codes for each api is not correct! for example, when I have 10 api I should write 10 different live data and fun ? this is my question

Comment: Then just use the solution described in thes answer. Load all categories at once. Get the result and put it in your single `LiveData`

Comment: Thanks, and how can I use this in fragment? How can I know which livedata is mobile , shirt or ...

Comment: I put my fragment codes in question. Please help me how can I call callProductData in fragment and use livedata. please and thanks dear friend <3

Comment: Depending on what you need you can store `HashMap<String, ProductList>` in your `MutableLiveData` or you can craete a new class for `data class NamedProductList(val name: String, val list: ProducList)`

Comment: Thanks, do you have free time? I'm amateur and really need your help. can you send to me full code?

Comment: Changed my answer. Added some more code.