# How to call API with Coroutines in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

In my application I have **3 APIs** and for this I write below codes. 
All of my APIs as the same and for this I write general call API fun such as below :

This codes worked for me, but I have strange bug! 
Sometime show **Mobile** and **Shoes** category data. sometime show **Shoes** and **Stationery** data. sometime show **one of category** data and sometime show **all of categories** data!

I think coroutines can help me, but I don't know how can I it?

Can you help me for fix this poblem?

Comment: You're firing off three api calls in your `init` block, which can complete in any order, so basically it's "last one wins" to update the `_items` LiveData. How you fix the problem depends on what you're actually trying to achieve, which you didn't explain. Start by reviewing coroutines [generally](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) , and [for Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines).

Comment: Why did you delete the code from your question? Now the question and answer don't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're funneling all your data from different sources into one LiveData. LiveData represents a state of something. It's not a reusable callback. You should have a separate LiveData for each of the types of requests you're making and observe each one independently.

If you did want to do this with coroutines, and without Flows (which would have the same requirement of one per request type as LiveData), then you could do something like this in the ViewModel. The reason to store these coroutines as Deferreds in a map is so they can be called repeatedly without having to repeat the time-consuming fetch.

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: HomeRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val fetches = ProductsCategories.values()
        .associateWith {
            viewModelScope.async { repository.getProductsList(it) }
        }

    suspend fun fetchFromApi(category: ProductsCategories): ResponseProductsList =
        fetches.getValue(category).await()
}
```

In Fragment:

```
// Mobile
viewLifecycleScope.launch {
    mobileProductsList.showShimmer()
    try {
        val result = viewModel.fetchFromApi(ProductsCategories.MOBILE)
        mobileProductsList.hideShimmer()
        // show results in recycler view
    } catch(e: IOException) {
        mobileProductsList.hideShimmer()
        // show error message
    }
}

// and likewise for other categories
```

I used try/catch but I don't know how `repository.getProductsList()` behaves. Maybe it returns a wrapped result already, so instead of try/catch you would handle the result in a when statement.

---

Edit: A different way to do this with LiveData is to use the `liveData` coroutine builder function. Your ViewModel could look like:

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: HomeRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val fetches = ProductsCategories.values()
        .associateWith {
            callApi(it)
        }

    fun getLiveData(category: ProductsCategories) =
        fetches.getValue(category)

    private fun callApi(category: ProductsCategories) = liveData<NetworkRequest> {
        val a = category.category
        emit(NetworkRequest.Loading())
        val response = repository.getProductsList(a)
        emit(NetworkResponse(response).generalNetworkResponse())
    }
}
```

And then in your Fragment:

```
// Mobile
viewModel.getLiveData(ProductsCategories.MOBILE).observe(viewLifecycleObserver) {
    when (it) {
        is NetworkRequest.Loading -> {
            mobileProductsList.showShimmer()
        }

        is NetworkRequest.Success -> {
            mobileProductsList.hideShimmer()
            it.data?.let { data ->
                //...
        }

        is NetworkRequest.Error -> {
            mobileProductsList.hideShimmer()
            root.showSnackBar(it.second.message!!)
        }
}

// and likewise for other categories
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, but show me `Not enough information to infer type variable V` error for **associateWith**

Comment: When use liveData  info associate show above error

Comment: I made a mistake in the example (used `liveData` in two places). I fixed it (but I haven't test it).